# Migrating a database from MS SQL to MySql - How time consuming / difficult is it?

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

A client wants a database converting from MS SQL to MySql.

Personally I wouldn't do this, I prefer MS SQL for larger databases and like the tools available when working with MSSQL.

However I do use MySql on smaller projects. I've never moved a database from one to the other, or made much use of sprocs when using mysql.

Is there a lot of work involved in rewriting the sprocs, considering I have no prior knowledge of the ms sql database itself, so will need to first gain an understanding of what each sproc does.

This isn't a discussion on which to use as that's already been decided by the client for a few reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you seen [this](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/migrating-from-microsoft.html)?

I haven't done this before, but I can only assure you mysql is good for big projects, too.